# Visible browser reflow

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm trying to make a window based application for web browsers. The number of windows is considerably high, so I'm storing them as HTML files (one per window) that I asynchronously retrieve from the server according to user interaction.

To add a window to the main page, I first add the *link* elements (CSS) of the downloaded document to its *head* section, and then I append the content of the *body* section to a certain *div*. When a window is closed, I just remove these elements.

This approach seems to be working nicely, but I can see that sometimes when I add a window, its elements are visible out of position with no style, and after a brief moment they are correctly painted.

I don't have a strong background in web programming, but I suspect this might be related to what it is called "browser reflow". Does it mean that it is taking too much time to repaint everything? Is it possible to just hide these "unstyled" elements until it is safe to show them?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time away from the computer seems to have relaxed my mind. I was erroneously assuming that adding new *link* elements to the *head* section would load the CSS files immediately. Obviously, the browser needs to retrieve them from the server first. So, the DOM elements I'm adding don't show their style because the CSS files have not been downloaded yet. I think this is the right answer.